# Hibernate - connecting to remote mysql database fails, when connecting to local succeeds

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, remote-access

I have 2 machines with identical databases.

I'm using hibernate version  **4.3.6.Final**

When I'm using this configuration (connecting to local DB) - everything is ok :

```
    <persistence-unit name="stg">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <!--
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        -->
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="PASSWORD"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DATABASENAME?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="3600"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="20"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="300"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.automaticTestTable" value="hibernate_conn_test"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="3600"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads" value="6"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The only thing that I changed is the IP to the other machine , and I always get the same error :

```
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://2.2.2.2:3306/te?autoReconnect=true"/>
```

This is the errors I'm getting:

```
[localhost-startStop-1][     ][13 Jan 2016 16:40:43,386] [internal.JdbcServicesImpl               ]: [WARN ] HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

[localhost-startStop-1][     ][13 Jan 2016 16:40:48,819] [hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate                    ]: [ERROR] HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2316)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:131)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:156)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:145)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.initializeAutomaticTestTable(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:898)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.createPooledConnectionPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:821)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:331)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:348)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at com.checkpoint.te.shared.service.CustomHibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(CustomHibernatePersistence.java:43)
    at com.checkpoint.te.shared.service.CustomHibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(CustomHibernatePersistence.java:28)
    at com.checkpoint.te.shared.sql.DbHandler.lifeCycleUp(DbHandler.java:192)
    at com.checkpoint.te.shared.BaseLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(BaseLifecycleListener.java:42)
    at com.checkpoint.te.shared.TomcatLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(TomcatLifecycleListener.java:13)
    at com.checkpoint.te.pod.PodLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PodLifecycleListener.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:358)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2489)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2334)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:308)
    ... 50 more
[localhost-startStop-1][     ][13 Jan 2016 16:40:48,825] [hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate                    ]: [ERROR] HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2316)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:131)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:156)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:145)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.initializeAutomaticTestTable(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:898)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.createPooledConnectionPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:821)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:331)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:348)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at com.checkpoint.te.shared.service.CustomHibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(CustomHibernatePersistence.java:43)
    at com.checkpoint.te.shared.service.CustomHibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(CustomHibernatePersistence.java:28)
    at com.checkpoint.te.shared.sql.DbHandler.lifeCycleUp(DbHandler.java:192)
    at com.checkpoint.te.shared.BaseLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(BaseLifecycleListener.java:42)
    at com.checkpoint.te.shared.TomcatLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(TomcatLifecycleListener.java:13)
    at com.checkpoint.te.pod.PodLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PodLifecycleListener.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:358)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2489)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2334)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:308)
    ... 50 more

Can anyone help?

I tried changing the port but nothing helper. Have no idea where to start

Comment: Did you try connecting to the remote database with mySql Workbench ?

Comment: did you ping the remote server?

Comment: Hey, yes there is a ping. I could not connect using mysql (I granted root with all priviledged) but for some reason I cound not connect remotely

Answer (score 0):

This screams "Network issue".

Check the following items:

- destination host can be reached on TCP 3306 (run `telnet destination 3306` or similar)
- check `netstat -na` while that connection is trying to establish: Any `SYN_SENT` would indicate a firewall is in the way.
- check `netstat -na` on your MySQL box - is 3306 **bound** to outside interface (or to 127.0.0.1 / localhost only?)